# Speed up reading a file to multiple bytes array and copy the offsets by if statement

Tags: c#, arrays

I use the below code to convert any file to byte array, then I'll convert it to Another byte array after search in array offsets.

How can I use Speed up reading the file to byte array to make my code optimized / faster, **And inside this while loop**. How I can create multiple bytes array if I search in what the offset contains ??

**For example :**
the file I open is completely loaded into a **memory**  is using buffer is good when I load a large file +50MB ?? or I can search for something else.

**Another thing :** Helping to create if statement inside while loop to search if the offset 100 for ex contains the byte **"00110011**"
if yes >> copy the offset to Other byte array
here is the code

```
 System.IO.FileStream fs = new System.IO.FileStream(openFileDialog1.FileName, System.IO.FileMode.Open);
  byte[] buf = new byte[102400];
  int bytesRead;

        // Read the file 100Kb at a time.

        do
        {

        bytesRead = fs.Read(buf, 0, 102400);



        string s = string.Join(" ", buf.Select(x => Convert.ToString(x, 2).PadLeft(8, '0')));

            MessageBox.Show("OK", "OK", MessageBoxButtons.OK);



           textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + s;
        }

        while (bytesRead == 102400);

        fs.Close();
```

Comment: Why do you think this code needs to be made unsafe? Have you profiled it? Also there are many other bugs you need to fix first, for example if you read a file that is not a multiple of 1048576 bytes large the last binary string you output will be padded with 0's to make it 1048576 bytes in size because you are converting the entire array, not just the amount that was read from the hard drive.

Comment: Hello, actually i need to convert this byte array to string. and again i need to convert the string to another array .. the problem is i when i convert to string and display it in textbox .. it's take long time ..  what i need is to make the string convert more optimized

Comment: Please explain in detail [by editing your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/23878458/edit) what you really want to accomplish. You are falling in to a [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) don't ask about how to fix your solution you came up with the problem you are having, just ask about the problem you are having itself.

Comment: Thank you Scott for helping me. so what is the better way than read 1048576 byte 1MB each time??

Comment: Sounds like a good question to be asked on Stack overflow, And a bad question to be asked **in the comments** of a question on Stack overflow. (And it really depends on what you are planning to do with that 1MB, that is why you should ask a new question or edit your old one explaining in detail what you are trying to do, showing what you have tried, and explaining why it is not working/getting unstatisfactory performance)

Comment: Your sample makes no sense - you claiming that you need to speed up code (and even use `unsafe` for that) but your sample shows some insane string manipulation code, including setting text field to something like 10+Mb of text. Please make your sample consistent with your need to speed up conversion. Concatenating/displaying  multi-megabyte strings are generally not what you want to see in performance sensitive code.

Comment: how i can contact you in private messages to tell you what i exactly need?

Comment: Sami, do not contact individuals in private messages; [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/23878458/edit), like Scott asked you to.

Comment: i'll edit my post to what exactly i need after convert it to string array

Comment: @ScottChamberlain is the editing good to explane what i need ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have fallen in the "I use bytes and arrays so I'm low level so the code will be fast" trap. C# and .NET provide its users with efficient abstractions to avoid this, in this case probably a [BinaryReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.IO.BinaryReader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and its [ReadString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader.readstring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.

You code has problems:

- You don't read the entire file (you stop at the last buffer of 1048576 bytes filled up, the next x bytes wont be read)
- You read a byte array then convert it to string ? you should use the .NET framework IO API (Streams) and allocate strings directly
- You should encapsulate IO operations on files in a 'using' statement to avoid resources leaks (on file handles).

Performance issues I see:

- Allocation of a big bytes array for nothing
- Convert calls that can be avoided

Code sample (I did not compile it but it gives you the idea of a clean and efficient file reading, see my MSDN links for more examples)

```
string myText = string.Empty;
using(var reader = new BinaryReader(openFileDialog1.FileName))
{
  string line;
  while((line = reader.ReadString()) != null)
  {
    myText += YouLogic(line); // use a StringBuilder if the number of string concatenations is high
  }
}
```

As a side note, for very big files, please consider using [C# Memory Mapped Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997372%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

EDIT:
BinaryReader contains Read methods for all the needed data types, it should allow you to efficiently read any type of binary file.

As for you additional question, look at [ReadBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader.readbytes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) from MSDN:

```
//Offset 100 bytes:
var offsetRead = reader.ReadBytes(100);
// read one byte
byte readByte = reader.ReadByte();
// compare it to the expected value
if(readByte == myByte)
{
   // copy the offset read
   var myArray = new byte[100];
   Array.Copy(offsetRead, myArray, offsetRead.Length);
   DoSomething(myArray);
}
```

Comment: thank you this code can read the byte offsets from 0 to file length?? then i want to make if statement inside while loop .. if the offset is "00110011" for ex... do something .. any idea ??

Comment: I edited my answer. Please consider asking different questions for different problems. Don't forget to accept answers that helped you.

Comment: Again.. Thank you for helping me.. but can i ask for editing something in this code??